# HTML file linking between directories

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, directory

My folder structure:

```
de/
    index.html
en/
    index.html
hu/
    index.html
img/
    image.png
style/
    stylesheet.css
```

How can I link to the css file in the `style` folder & the image in the `img` folder **within** the html file inside the `de` folder, *whithout* having to type the entire hostname like `http://myhost.com/style/style.css`?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
../style/stylesheet.css

../img/image.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relative path: `../style/style.css`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work like this:
`<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="../style/stylesheet.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>`

Comment: what is the url for the html page you're loading ?

Comment: http://hunpony.hu/today/index-developer-version-qdtjo.html
(notice how it doesn't load the custom fonts)

Answer (score 1):

The css file can be link in the html file as

```
<link href="../style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to type the domain, you should use

`<link href="/style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

but dont forget the first `/` as this will mean that the address is on the same domain as the page.
this will also save you from maintenance problems if you ever change the directory structure of your website.